# "See you Monday at 10AM" vs "See you on Monday at 10AM"

Tags: commas, time, dates

Is it correct to say/write "See you Monday at 10AM"?

Comment: Yes, but to a Brit it sounds rather American. In the UK, we prefer to keep the preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping the preposition (on) is less formal, but still correct in this case.

There is some discussion of this on a [sister site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26811/when-can-we-omit-the-preposition-on-before-weekdays), for what it's worth.